# how can i search facebook user based on diffrent parameter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iphone app.
in which how can i search facebook user based on different parameters like name,college,city?

I know there is api for search user https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user.
I have tried to search this way with FbGraphApi  [FacebookGraph doGraphGet:@"search?q=Bhavesh&type=user" withGetVars:nil];

But, i am getting this error.
" {"error":{"message":"Unsupported type, user?","type":"Exception"}} "

i don't know what's proper way to use this api.
please help me with this.

Comment: i found that i need to search with access token, now i am doing that way but all i am getting is  { "data":[ ] } totally blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=SEARCH?type=user&access_token=YOUR ACCESS_TOKEN. you can pass anything in place of "SEARCH". it can search by name,id,email.